# Resque worker not starting

Tags: sinatra, resque, padrino

I am using resque with padrino, and created a new worker when I call Resque.enqueue WorkerClassHere, 1 it shows up in the resque UI as a queue with a new pending job. However, when I try and start a worker for this queue nothing happens. I have tried all of the QUEUE= rake resque tasks out there with no luck thus far. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure redis is running:

```
$ redis-server &
$ redis-cli ping
PONG
```

Generate binstubs:

```
$ bundle --binstubs
```

Work through your queue:

```
$ bin/resque work
```

If that doesn't work, post error messages.

Comment: I added the task :environment to the rake file and ran rake resque:work QUEUE=my queue and it started up but I need it to run in the background and not in the same terminal session not sure about how to achieve that. Thank you for the help.

Comment: check out `foreman` http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html

Comment: for a bash / zsh shell you can use `&` to run things in the background and then `fg 1` or `fg 2` to bring them to the foreground again as well